# Compute average of data between time period in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table named IMETERDATA:

```
DEVNAME VARCHAR2(25)
DEVID   VARCHAR2(8)
USEDATE TIMESTAMP(6)
INSTANTPOWER    NUMBER(3,0)
TOTALENERGY NUMBER(7,4)
ROWNUMBER   NUMBER(4,0)
```

I want to compute and show average of Totalenergy on 2-hour interval. For instance, if I have a data for specific date (e.g. Nov 22, 2016), I want to calculate average of Totalenergy for period of: 12am-2am, 2am-4am .... 10pm-12pm. I want to calculate the average for all dates with specified interval. What I have done so far:

```
    select to_number(to_char(USEDATE, 'HH24')) as "HOUR", 
    avg(TOTALENERGY) as "AVERAGE", TRUNC(USEDATE, 'DD') as "DATE"
    from IMETERDATA 
    WHERE TRUNC(USEDATE) in (select DISTINCT(TRUNC(USEDATE, 'DD')) 
    from IMETERDATA) and (to_number(to_char(USEDATE, 'HH24')) >= 12 and to_number(to_char(USEDATE, 'HH24')) < 14 )
    group by to_number(to_char(USEDATE, 'HH24')), TRUNC(USEDATE, 'DD');
```

This query gives only average from 12pm to 2pm.How can I calculate for 24 hours? I want result from 12am to 11.59pm with interval of 2 hours:

```
12AM - 2AM ---> 58.50
2AM - 4AM ----> 60.35
   ...
10PM - 11.59PM --> 40.35
```

Comment: You need create a hour ranges table, with `start_time, end_time` then join to your query so every hour get a range. Then group by ranges

Comment: Hmm. Can I do it without creating another table? I tried to do in .psp file when loop changes the hour but it was messy.

Comment: what is psp? You can use a temporal query using `WITH`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am using PSP (PL/SQL Server Page) to display the query in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

> Hmm. Can I do it without creating another table?

Sure. Use a query like below (this example generates 2-hour periods for 2 days):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'
;
SELECT date '2016-11-22' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 2 * (level - 1), 'HOUR' ) as period_start
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 * 12 ; -- 2 days of 12 "two hours" periods

PERIOD_START   
----------------
2016-11-22 00:00
2016-11-22 02:00
2016-11-22 04:00
2016-11-22 06:00
2016-11-22 08:00
2016-11-22 10:00
2016-11-22 12:00
2016-11-22 14:00
2016-11-22 16:00
2016-11-22 18:00
2016-11-22 20:00
2016-11-22 22:00
2016-11-23 00:00
2016-11-23 02:00
2016-11-23 04:00
2016-11-23 06:00
2016-11-23 08:00
2016-11-23 10:00
2016-11-23 12:00
2016-11-23 14:00
2016-11-23 16:00
2016-11-23 18:00
2016-11-23 20:00
2016-11-23 22:00

 24 rows selected
```

And then join a result of the above query to your table and calculate averages

```
SELECT x.PERIOD_START,
       AVG( i.TOTALENERGY )
FROM (
   the_above_query
) x
JOIN IMETERDATA i
ON i.USEDATE >= x.PERIOD_START AND i.USEDATE < x.PERIOD_START + interval '2' hour
GROUP BY x.PERIOD_START
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if I have multiple days? How can I select period of 30 days?

Comment: A few examples: period of 30 days --> `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30 * 12 ;`, period of 300 days => `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 300 * 12 ; `, period of 3 million days ==> `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3000000 * 12 ; `

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Analytic Functions: windowing_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#i97640), there you can do it straight forward.

```
select USEDATE, 
    AVG(TOTALENERGY) OVER (ORDER BY USEDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING) as AVERAGE,
    MIN(USEDATE) OVER (ORDER BY USEDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING) as INTERVAL_START,
    MAXUSEDATE) OVER (ORDER BY USEDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING) as INTERVAL_END
from IMETERDATA;
```

This query gives you all averages for each time +/- 1 hour (i.e. 2 hours).
If you need just the times of given hours you can use

```
with t as 
   (select USEDATE, 
      AVG(TOTALENERGY) OVER (ORDER BY USEDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING) as AVERAGE,
      MIN(USEDATE) OVER (ORDER BY USEDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING) as INTERVAL_START,
      MAXUSEDATE) OVER (ORDER BY USEDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING) as INTERVAL_END
    from IMETERDATA)
select *
from t
where USEDATE = TRUNC(USEDATE, 'HH')
   AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM USEDATE) IN (1,3,5,7,...);
```

Instead of `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM USEDATE) IN (1,3,5,7,...)` you could also use `MOD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM USEDATE), 1) = 1`

Maybe this is not 100% what you are looking for (your question is not so clear in that regards) but I assume you get an idea how to use it.